# Sitecore show .pdf extension on download link

Tags: pdf, sitecore

Noticed that out of box, the sitecore renders images, pdf or any doc with .ashx extension.

Would be nice to preserve the item's original extension e.g. bla.pdf

Could someone please advise what's the best way to achieve this without any adverse impact?

I've seen implementation below:

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="" />
```

Not sure whether there would be any adverse  impact on performance or similar.

Answer (score 3):

The setting you refer to is the correct one.
There is no major adverse impact.

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="" />
```

And the old url with .ashx also continues to work. It is not on by default it is something from the past, compatiblity it takes a wildcard mapping to the ASP.NET ISAPI dll.

If you want to optimize for performance you can take a look to this [Performance degradation when the media link prefix contains tilde](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/723979)

Comment: In fact, ANY extension works, e.g. you ca request it with a .png extension and it will still serve the PDF

Comment: @JammyKam Unless you implement a solution like this http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/handling-duplicate-media-paths-in.html

Comment: @MartinDavies I'm aware of your post and was thinking about that when I commented. My only concern would be performance since most of the time it's not an issue if the file is served up with the incorrect extension since the mime type is set correclty.